# Line title up with tabular environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, titles

I'm trying to alter how a `\documentclass{report}` title page appears for a package I'm putting together for work.  I've cobbled together enough knowledge to make it *very close* to what I want, but I'm stuck now.

A MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}

\title{An exceptionally long title that probably needs to look better than it does, and will span multiple lines}
\author{Company!\\Street!\\City!, State! ZIP!}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{\begin{titlepage}
  \let\footnotesize\small
  \let\footnoterule\relax
  \let \footnote \thanks
    \begin{flushleft}
        \includegraphics[width=10cm]{example-image-a}
    \end{flushleft}
  \vfill 
  \begin{flushright}
    {\LARGE \@title}
    \vskip 3em
    {\large
     \lineskip .75em
      \begin{tabular}[t]{l}
        \@author
      \end{tabular}\par}
      \vskip 1.5em
  \end{flushright}
\end{titlepage}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Lorem Ipsum}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

This provides the following output:
[image]

but I want the title to line up with the address.  I've tried putting the title in the `\tabular` environment but things went haywire and my constant tweaking couldn't fix it.

How can I make the title--regardless of title length--line up with the *right* edge of the address?

Comment: You seem to have some spurious spaces in your input, but the `Brief article` will not align with the tabular this way!

Comment: Not sure where the spaces are coming from, but I do try to keep my code aligned with tabs/spaces so that it's easier for me to read in my editor.

Comment: @Steven: I've updated my answer to accommodate your needs. It seems to do what you ask.

Comment: Isn't `\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}\@author\end{tabular}` sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to maintain an appropriate alignment between the title and the author, set it in the same `tabular` that has a single column that is `l`eft aligned (removing the inter-column gap on the right via `@{}`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{lipsum,graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}

\title{Brief article with a very long title}
\author{Company! \\ Street! \\ City!, State! ZIP!}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
  \begin{titlepage}
    \let\footnotesize\small
    \let\footnoterule\relax
    \let\footnote\thanks
    \noindent \includegraphics[width=10cm]{example-image}

    \vfill 

    \noindent{\raggedleft\LARGE \@title\par}

    \bigskip

    \mbox{}\hfill
    {\large\begin{tabular}{l@{}}
      \@author
    \end{tabular}}

    \vspace{1.5em}
  \end{titlepage}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Lorem Ipsum}
\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

The title is set using `\raggedleft`, allowing it to stretch across the entire title page if need be and ragged-wrap as required.

There is no need to additional packages to move content left/right on the page. Either set it inside a `\raggedright`/`\raggedleft` paragraph, or move content over to the right via `\mbox{}\hfill<stuff>`. `\mbox{}` sets a "mark" containing nothing, from which `\hfill` can stretch over to the right side of the page.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}

\title{Brief Article}
\author{Company!\\Street!\\City!, State! ZIP!}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
  \begin{titlepage}
    \let\footnotesize\small%
    \let\footnoterule\relax%
    \let\footnote\thanks%
    \begin{flushleft}%
      \includegraphics[width=10cm]{example-image-a}%
    \end{flushleft}%
    \vfill%
    \begin{flushright}
      {\large%
        \begin{tabular}[t]{l}
          \LARGE\@title \\
          \tabularnewline[.75em]%
          \@author%
        \end{tabular}%
      }%
      \vskip1.5em%
    \end{flushright}%
  \end{titlepage}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\maketitle%
\section{Lorem Ipsum}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

A version without `flushright` and `flushleft`:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{showframe}

\title{A long stupid title that should not be there!}
\author{Company!\\Street!\\City!, State! ZIP!}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
  \begin{titlepage}
    \let\footnotesize\small%
    \let\footnoterule\relax%
    \let\footnote\thanks%
    {%
      \RaggedRight
      \includegraphics[width=10cm]{example-image-a}%
    }
    \vfill%
    {%
      \RaggedLeft
      {\large%
        \begin{tabular}[t]{p{0.3\textwidth}}
          \LARGE\@title \\
          \tabularnewline[.75em]
          \@author
        \end{tabular}%
      }%

      \vskip1.5em
     }%
  \end{titlepage}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\maketitle%
\section{Lorem Ipsum}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this makes the title line up with the address but if the title is exceptionally long, then things fall apart.

Comment: @Steven: Your demo title is not exceptionally long -- you're changing the question right now

Comment: Hmm.  You're right.  My apologies.  Honestly I hadn't considered it until your first answer.

Comment: @Steven: Have you seen my update at all? ;-)

Comment: After seen the excellent example you provided, I'm changing the question yet again, mostly because of the appearance of a long-titled report.

Comment: @Steven: yes, but question changing is not very nice -- it kills all efforts that have been made so far!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41225/discussion-between-steven-and-christian-hupfer).